# How can I directly reflect the state in react?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

When I executed the onlike function, I succeeded in immediately showing iconName="unlike" when liked or like2 was false. However, if the onUnlike function is executed, iconName="unlike" is displayed after 0.5 seconds.

I think the reason is because like2 is used incorrectly as a ternary operator.
How to code ternary operator to show iconName="like" immediately when like2 is true?

this is my code

```
    const onLike = () => {
      setLike2(true);
    };

    const onUnlike = () => {
      setLike2(false);
    };

    {liked || like2 ? (
      <LikeContainer>
        <MenuContainer onPress={onUnlike}>
          <IconButtonU
            iconName="unlike"
            style={{width: 23, height: 23}}
            source={require('../../Assets/Images/Tabs/heart.png')}
          />
        </MenuContainer>
      </LikeContainer>
    ) : (
      <LikeContainer>
        <MenuContainer onPress={onLike}>
          <IconButtonU
            iconName="like"
            source={require('../../Assets/Images/Tabs/ic_favorite_outline.png')}
          />

        </MenuContainer>
      </LikeContainer>
    )}
```

Comment: Why are there two variables `liked` and `like2`? Are they not tracking the same piece of data?

Comment: @BrianThompson liked is the data received from the server, but it came too slowly when the value came, so I added like2.

Comment: Are you using a `useEffect` to update the server with the new value in another part of the code? If so, it sounds like the delay is due to the async request, and you might just need to change to `{liked && like2 ?`